# Debug port forwarding for using Jupyter notebook remotely

Tags: ssh, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to use Jupyter notebook on a remote computer. The setup is as follows: I have my home laptop, which can ssh to a specific computer on my university's network (e.g., `gateway.myuniv.edu`). Once I am logged to `gateway.myuniv.edu`, I can ssh to the computer on which I would like to run the Jupyter notebook server (e.g. `cluster.myuniv.edu`).

**What works**: I can run the server on the gateway and connect to it from my laptop using local port forwarding, as follows:

On `gateway.myuniv.edu`: `$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888`

On my laptop: `$ ssh -v -N -L 9000:localhost:8888 myusername@gateway.myuniv.edu`

Then on my laptop's browser, I open the url: `http://localhost:9000`

**What doesn't work**: I don't want to run the server on the gateway, since I can't do heavy computations there. I tried to do the following:

On `cluster.myuniv.edu`: `$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888`

On my laptop: `$ ssh -v -N -L 9000:cluster.myuniv.edu:8888 myusername@gateway.myuniv.edu`

Then on my laptop's browser, I open the url: `http://localhost:9000`. This doesn't work: SSH says that the connection is refused.

I don't understand why this would happen and how to debug this, would be happy for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are forwarding port `:8888` on `cluster.myuniv.edu` to port `:9000` on `gateway.myuniv.edu` and then forwarding port `:8888` on `gateway.myuniv.edu` to port `9000` on your laptop.

The solution would the following:

On cluster.myuniv.edu: `$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888`

On gateway.myuniv.edu: `$ ssh -v -N -L 8888:localhost:8888 myusername@cluster.myuniv.edu`

On laptop: `$ ssh -v -N -L 9000:localhost:8888 myusername@gateway.myuniv.edu`

I would also recommend that you run Jupyter notebook (on the cluster) and the ssh tunneling (on the gateway) using Tmux or Screen so it remains active even if you close terminal

Comment: This almost works: The command on the gateway should ssh to cluster: `$ ssh -v -N -L 8888:localhost:8888 myusername@cluster.myuniv.edu`. When I do it like that, it works. I edited your response - thanks!

Comment: thanks!  I am glad you got it working. Can you please mark the question as answered?

Comment: Sure. One last thing, could you explain why does `ssh -v -N -L 9000:cluster.myuniv.edu:8888 myusername@gateway.myuniv.edu` leads to me forwarding port `:8888` on `cluster.myuniv.edu` to port `:9000` on `gateway.myuniv.edu` and then forwarding port `:8888` on `gateway.myuniv.edu` to port `9000` on my laptop? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Hopefully this explanation helps: so basically you are running ipython notebook on `:8888` on the cluster.  To connect to the cluster you need to connect through the gateway.  This means you are connecting:

Laptop -> Gateway -> Cluster

Now its on `:8888` on cluster, so you choose a port on the gateway to tunnel to `:8888` on the cluster.  We choose `:8888` as well (you can choose anything you want).  Now finally we tunnel to the gateway and forward `:8888` to `:9000` on our laptop

Comment: This also should work:

On Cluster: `$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888`

On Gateway: `$ ssh -v -N -L 8001:localhost:8888`

On Laptop: `$ ssh -v -N -L 9000:localhost:8001 myusername@gateway.myuniv.edu`

Comment: Thanks. This explains in detail why your solution works, which I understand, but not why my original one line solution fails, which I don't understand.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood your question.  I am not sure why the one liner doesn't work.  It might be worth asking a new question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gateway.myuniv.edu as a Jump (ssh -J) host.

1. So start jupyter notebook on your cluster as you normally do:
   `jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888`
2. On your local laptop: `ssh username@cluster.myuniv.edu -J username@gateway.myuniv.edu -L 8888:localhost:8888 -N`